# Nginx проксирование запросов к api работает не так, как я ожидаю

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

У меня есть backend сервер на express и обратный прокси на nginx. По пути example.com/ отдается статика, а по пути example.com/api/ запрос должен уходить к express на порту 3000. В мир должен смотреть только порт 80. При запросе на example.com/api/ nginx показывает "An error occurred." код ошибки 502. А при запросе на example.com:3000/api/ отрабатывает как нужно. Тут точно косяк в конфиге nginx...

nginx.conf

```
http {
    include        /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    sendfile       on;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        gzip_static on;    
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

dockerfile сервера

запускал через docker run -d --name server -p 3000:3000 img-name

```
FROM node:11-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /server/src
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

код сервера

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(3000,
    () => console.log('Server start on port 3000'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({test: 'Got a GET request from /'});
});

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.send({testApi: 'Got a GET request from /api'});
});
```

Comment: попробуйте  location ~ ^/api

Comment: скорее всего вам нужно объеденить контейнеры в одну сеть, и всесто `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000` использовать `http://<nodejs_container_name>:3000`

Comment: Это через docker compose и network в них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне и посоветовали, я связал контейнеры в одну сеть следующим образом:

1. Создал сеть my-net

```
docker network create my-net
```

2. Связал 2 контейнера nginx и server

```
docker network connect my-net nginx
docker network connect my-net server
```

3. Подправил файл nginx.conf

```
location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://server:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

После чего по адресу example.com/api/ идет проксирование в express.

Comment: пометь свой ответ "принятым", если сайт позволяет